# Dynamic Dropdown Menu on Spring Webflow

Tags: java, dynamic, drop-down-menu, spring-webflow

I want to know the best way to implement dynamic dropdown menus in a Spring Webflow environment.

I have been googling for the last 3 hours and I have several ideas about how achieving it. My question is related to know the best solution in terms of cleanliness and best practices.

I'm thinking about creating a Spring MVC controller which receive an AJAX request with my required parameters and sends in the response a list in JSON. That request would be created with jQuery so the response would be treated as well with jQuery, creating updating the required dropdown menu.

Furthermore, whatever the solution, I would like to avoid creating directly each  tag in the jQuery handler. Doesn't provide jQuery a mechanism or utility that for example, updates a dropdown menu by receiving an array?

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.

```
<form:form commandName="dateRange">
    <!-- ... -->
    <select name="fyForDR" id="fyForDR" class='discretFont' style='margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;'>
        <option value="" selected='selected'>Fiscal Year</option>
        <option value="2011" <c:if test="${fyForDR == '2011'}">selected="selected"</c:if> >FY11</option>
        <option value="2010" <c:if test="${fyForDR == '2010'}">selected="selected"</c:if> >FY10</option>
        <option value="2009" <c:if test="${fyForDR == '2009'}">selected="selected"</c:if> >FY09</option>
        <option value="2008" <c:if test="${fyForDR == '2008'}">selected="selected"</c:if> >FY08</option>
        <option value="2007" <c:if test="${fyForDR == '2007'}">selected="selected"</c:if> >FY07</option>
        <option value="2006" <c:if test="${fyForDR == '2006'}">selected="selected"</c:if> >FY06</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
            elementId: "fyForDR",
            event: "onchange",
            formId:"dateRange",
            params: {fragments:"body", _eventId: "setFy"}
        }));
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
</form:form>
```

Comment: techsjs2012 thanks for your answer. As I understand, you are reloading the dropdown menu which ID is "fyForDR" by triggering the event "setFy", and then I guess you have some code inside your transition that loads a list of values, am I wrong? What I don't understand at all is why you do that if you already have elements in  the dropdown menu. With your solution you are losing the original content every time the "onchange" event is triggered, isn't it? Could you explain a little bit more the behavior of your solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do it so after the user clicks on one of the options I removed everything but that one option